# Replacing in list inside list in R

Tags: r, list, replace

I have a list of lists like the following:

```
x <- list(x = list(a = 1:10, b = 10:20), y = 4, z = list(a = 1, b = 2))

str(x)

List of 3
 $ x:List of 2
  ..$ a: int [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
  ..$ b: int [1:11] 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 ...
 $ y: num 4
 $ z:List of 2
  ..$ a: num 1
  ..$ b: num 2
```

How can I replace values in the list "a" inside list "x" (x$a) to replace for example the 1 with 100.

My real data is very large so I cannot do it one by one and the unlist function is not a solution for me because I miss information.

Any ideas??

Comment: Do you want to change 1 in list z$a as well?

Comment: No, only in x. The rest should remain stay as is :)

Comment: `x$x$a[x$x$a == 1] <- 100`?

Comment: No, have you checked the output? I have tried something similar also but does not work...

Comment: @Maël solution works fine given the example input.

Comment: Oooh, yes. It is true. Thank you @sindri_baldur for checking it. In my real data it does not work. I am checking it. I think the problem is that in my list the "Type" is double [250 x 1000]", while in my example it is just double [10], which makes the replacing easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Operate on all a subcomponents

For the list x shown in the question we can check whether each component is a list with an `a` component and if so then replace 1 in the `a` component with 100.

```
f <- function(z) { if (is.list(z) && "a" %in% names(z)) z$a[z$a == 1] <- 100; z }
lapply(x, f)
```

### Just x component

**1)** If you only want to perform the replacement in the x component of x then x2 is the result.

```
x2 <- x
x2$x$a[x2$x$a == 1] <- 100
```

**2)** Another possibility for the operating on just the x component is to use rrapply.

```
library(rrapply)

cond <- function(z, .xparents) identical(.xparents, c("x", "a"))
rrapply(x, cond, function(z) replace(z, z == 1, 100))
```

**3)** And another possibility is to use modifyList

```
modifyList(x, list(x = list(a = replace(x$x$a, x$x$a ==1, 100))))
```

**4)** within is another option.

```
within(x, x$a[x$a == 1] <- 100 )
```

**4a)** or iterating within:

```
within(x, x <- within(x, a[a == 1] <- 100) )
```

Comment: I have all the time an error like "Error in x$a[x$a == 1] <- 100 :   (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'" I should update the question because it is a little more complicated

Comment: I had mistyped it the first time but changed it later.  See revision.

Comment: the second option you mentioned worked even in my real data, which was more complicated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is trick using `relist` + `unlist`

```
> v <- unlist(x)

> relist(replace(v, grepl("\\.a\\d?", names(v)) & v == 1, 100), x)
$x
$x$a
 [1] 100   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10

$x$b
 [1] 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20


$y
[1] 4

$z
$z$a
[1] 100

$z$b
[1] 2
```